# Trigger code on program termination

Tags: python, delete-file, termination

My script creates files to store data for the duration of its run time, I would like to delete these files **on termination** of my program. Is this possible?

I DO NOT want suggestions for a work around ... like 'don't create files'.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about the os module of Python ? There is a "remove()" method to do what you want.

See the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.remove)

To handle the exit of your program, you can use [atexit](http://docs.python.org/library/atexit.html) module.

Example:

```
import os

def delete_file(name):
    os.remove(name)

import atexit
atexit.register(delete_file, file_path)
```

file_path is the file to delete.

Comment: You should catch the exceptions that os.remove can raise (e.g. if removing a file on Windows that is in use.)

Answer (score 6):

You want the [atexit()](http://docs.python.org/library/atexit.html) handlers.

In my experience, perhaps due to bugs in the interpreter(?), I found these very challenging to use, as sometimes the resources I needed to use had already been cleaned up, including modules I needed to use.

Answer (score 1):

Python offers support for `tempfiles` (see module of the same name). These may not be guaranteed to be deleted when the program terminates, but the OS knows that they can be deleted without notice whenever desired (e.g. on some Unixes, every night).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simpler method that seems to work correctly. I haven't used it in real code, so there may be shortcomings I don't know about. Critiques from more experienced Pythonistas are welcome.

```
import sys

def main():
    print('main')
    sys.exit(0)

try:
    main()
finally:
    print('cleanup code goes here')
```

Comment: Or you just put the try/finally inside `main()`. This works if the files are controlled by the main application, but if they're part of a library, then it will be necessary to play with `atexit` handlers.